# Problem reducing an array with numbs (Javascript)

Tags: json

I have a problem when adding elements to an array, to reduce it later (I need the total price for a cart)

This part push values that I fetch from an API into an array, but they seem to be added as objects and not as successive numbers (console for example show me "[]" with details like "0: 28 1: 35 3: 28" when I open it, instead of [28, 35, 28] ; and it is the same behavior if I enter directly a numbered value instead of a variable) :

```
let allPriceSums = [];

const getProductInfo = new Request(http://localhost:3000/api/teddies/${productInStorage.sentProductId});
        fetch(getProductInfo)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(model => {
                const getProductPrice = (model.price / 100);
                allPriceSums.push(getProductPrice);  // adding the sum to the array
                productInCartPrice.innerHTML = Prix : <b><i>${getProductPrice},00&euro;</i></b>;
            })
            .catch(error => productInCartPrice.innerHTML = "");
```

Then, when I want to reduce the array (the values I want to get are correct), it returns 0.

```
const totalCartPrice = allPriceSums.reduce(function (accumulator, currentValue) {
        return accumulator + currentValue;
    }, 0);
```

I tried to use .map in various ways to convert the elements of the array to numbers, with no result (the reduce function is working with an array of numbers)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the problem you are facing is in async nature of `getProductInfo`, where you get product's price and push it to array `allPriceSums`, whereas `totalCartPrice` is sync by nature, which means, that it doesn't wait the async `getProductInfo` finishes the job.

Check twice where in your code do you call the `totalCartPrice` calculation?